# Syntax Error with Named Range

Tags: vba, excel, syntax-error

I cannot seem to get the syntax corrects as follows:

Sheet(DCRLog) has a named range at AE365 called  EndSrtRnge

I am trying to sort the spreadsheet From A3 to AE365

```
Dim StSrtRnge As Range
Set StSrtRnge = Range("A3")

Dim NdSrtRnge As Range
Set NdSrtRnge = Range("EndSrtRnge")

Dim SortRnge As Range
Set SortRnge = Range(StSrtRnge:NdSrtRnge)*********Syntax Error
```

The final Statement used is

```
SortRnge.Sort Key1:=SortKey, Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use :

```
Set SortRnge = Range(StSrtRnge,NdSrtRnge)
```

Or with your syntax, you need :

```
Set SortRnge = Range(StSrtRnge.Address & ":" & NdSrtRnge.Address)
```

Comment: Much Appreciated, Thanks

Comment: @ChrisSmith : You are welcome! Btw, when an answer solved your issue you should accept it (grayed tick under the votes) to mark your question as answered! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Range expects two cells separated by a comma or a string address.
Currently `RANGE("A3")` and `Range("EndSrtRnge")` may be on different sheets if the wrong sheet is acitve when `Range("A3")` is set - you haven't specified the sheet it's on.

```
Sub Test()

Dim NdSrtRnge As Range
Set NdSrtRnge = Range("EndSrtRnge")

Dim StSrtRnge As Range
'Ensure the start range is on the same sheet as the named range.
'Using just RANGE will place it on the currently active sheet.
Set StSrtRnge = NdSrtRnge.Parent.Range("A3")

Dim SortRnge As Range
Set SortRnge = NdSrtRnge.Parent.Range(StSrtRnge, NdSrtRnge)

End Sub
```

Just double checked - setting `EndSrtRnge` on `Sheet1` and then selecting `Sheet2` before running the code produced an `Application-defined or object-defined error` when using just `Range("A3")`.